# Error when using EU Advanced Signature with Templates

Tags: docusignapi

I'm getting an error when finishing a DocuSign Ceremony using EU Advanced Signature with Templates. The odd thing is that it was working before and still working for ceremonies that have an embedded PDF.

When finishing a ceremony the following error is popping up:

[image]

The envelope history shows more details:

[image]

It mentions the userEmail, so I've double-checked the JSON and everything seems to be fine, after all, I didn't get any error when creating the envelope.

Here's the JSON using a Template that is failing:

```
    {
      "status": "sent",
      "eventNotification": {
        "recipientEvents": [
          {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "delivered"
          },
          {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "completed"
          },
          {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "sent"
          },
          {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "declined"
          }
        ],
        "envelopeEvents": [
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined"
          }
        ]
      },
      "emailSubject": "Contract",
      "compositeTemplates": [
        {
          "serverTemplates": [
            {
              "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID",
              "sequence": "1"
            }
          ],
          "inlineTemplates": [
            {
              "sequence": "1",
              "recipients": {
                "signers": [
                  {
                    "routingOrder": "2",
                    "roleName": "Signer 2",
                    "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                      {
                        "signatureProviderOptions": {
                          "sms": "+00999555585"
                        },
                        "signatureProviderName": "UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP"
                      }
                    ],
                    "recipientId": "2",
                    "name": "Axel Foley",
                    "emailNotification": {
                      "supportedLanguage": "en",
                      "emailSubject": "CUSTOM_MESSAGE",
                      "emailBody": "CUSTOM_MESSAGE"
                    },
                    "email": " axel.foley@email.com"
                  },
                  {
                    "routingOrder": "2",
                    "roleName": "Signer 3",
                    "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                      {
                        "signatureProviderOptions": {
                          "sms": "+00123456789"
                        },
                        "signatureProviderName": "UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP"
                      }
                    ],
                    "recipientId": "3",
                    "name": "Alex Murphy",
                    "emailNotification": {
                      "supportedLanguage": "en",
                      "emailSubject": "CUSTOM_MESSAGE",
                      "emailBody": "CUSTOM_MESSAGE"
                    },
                    "email": "alex.murphy@email.com"
                  }
                ],
                "inPersonSigners": [
                  {
                    "signerName": "Leeroy Jenkins",
                    "signerEmail": "leeroy.jenkins@email.com",
                    "routingOrder": "1",
                    "roleName": "Signer 1",
                    "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                      {
                        "signatureProviderOptions": {
                          "sms": "+00666888777"
                        },
                        "signatureProviderName": "UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP"
                      }
                    ],
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "hostName": "Lightning McQueen",
                    "hostEmail": "lightning.mcqueen@email.com",
                    "emailNotification": {
                      "supportedLanguage": "en",
                      "emailSubject": "CUSTOM_MESSAGE",
                      "emailBody": "CUSTOM_MESSAGE"
                    },
                    "clientUserId": "SFDC_CLIENT_USER_ID"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "customFields": {
                "textCustomFields": [
                  {
                    "value": "SFDC_ID",
                    "show": "false",
                    "required": "false",
                    "name": "##SFContract"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

And here's the JSON with an embedded PDF that works fine:

```
    {
      "status": "sent",
      "recipients": {
        "inPersonSigners": [
          {
            "tabs": {
              "signHereTabs": [
                {
                  "anchorYOffset": "0",
                  "anchorXOffset": "0",
                  "anchorUnits": "inches",
                  "anchorString": "\\s1\\",
                  "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false"
                }
              ]
            },
            "signerName": "Vincent Vega",
            "signerEmail": "vicent.vega@email.com",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "roleName": "Signer 1",
            "recipientSignatureProviders": [
              {
                "signatureProviderOptions": {
                  "sms": "+00789456123"
                },
                "signatureProviderName": "UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP"
              }
            ],
            "recipientId": "1",
            "hostName": "Lightning McQueen",
            "hostEmail": "lightning.mcqueen@email.com",
            "emailNotification": {
              "supportedLanguage": "en",
              "emailSubject": "CUSTOM_MESSAGE",
              "emailBody": "CUSTOM_MESSAGE"
            },
            "clientUserId": "SFDC_CLIENT_USER_ID"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventNotification": {
        "recipientEvents": [
          {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "delivered"
          },
          {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "completed"
          },
          {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "sent"
          },
          {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "declined"
          }
        ],
        "envelopeEvents": [
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
          },
          {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined"
          }
        ]
      },
      "documents": [
        {
          "name": "Form.pdf",
          "fileExtension": "pdf",
          "documentId": "1",
          "documentBase64": "BASE64_PDF"
        }
      ],
      "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [
          {
            "value": "SFDC_ID",
            "show": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "name": "##SFAccount"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Am I missing something? Have anyone ever seen this error before?

It's worth to mention that I'm getting the error right in the first signature (InPerson).

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that is a known issue of DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue during an in-person signing session when the signer clicks on Finished, he should get the following popup [image]

If you don’t set any email, it will fail with the CONSTRAINT_VALIDATION_ERROR

The workaround is to specify an email.